# CXF: corrupted schemaLocation in xsd:import

Tags: soap, wsdl, cxf

I'm deploying a SOAP webservice using Apache CXF on different servers. The WSDL contains this line:

```
<xsd:import 
namespace="http://schemas.xxx.net/xsd/gameserver/types/types_v1_0"
schemaLocation="types_v1_0.xsd">
```

when a client accesses the WSDL, the `schemaLocation` is completed to form an absolute path:

```
<xsd:import 
namespace="http://schemas.xxx.net/xsd/gameserver/type/types_v1_0" 
schemaLocation="http://moss.xxx.local:8080/gameserver/webservices/base_v1?xsd=types_v1_0.xsd">
```

My problem: on some of the servers, this produces corrupt URLs:

```
<xsd:import 
namespace="http://schemas.xxx.net/xsd/gameserver/types/types_v1_0" 
schemaLocation="http://localhost8888gameserver/webservices/base_v1?xsd=types_v1_0.xsd">
```

or even

```
<xsd:import 
namespace="http://schemas.xxx.net/xsd/gameserver/types/types_v1_0" 
schemaLocation="jen.x.local8080gameserver/webservices/base_v1?xsd=types_v1_0.xsd">
```

Has anyone encountered this problem? What could cause it? It seems to have appeared suddenly today when deploying a current version of the application, but I cannot find any suspicious changes - specifically that WSDL was not changed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the URL is derived from the `publishedEndpointUrl` attribute of the `<jaxws:endpoint>` element in `cxf-context.xml`, which was wrong on some servers due to problems in the Maven profiles.

Comment: So… is this a localized problem or is there something that could help others?

Comment: @Donal: Well, the fact that the base URL for schemaLocation in the WSDL import element is determined by publishedEndpointUrl in that XML configuration file is not exactly obvious and could cause confusion for anyone working with CXF.

Comment: I was just trying to see if there was a way in which your answer could be made helpful enough to others. :-) For example, if the problem was really due to the presence of backslashes in the endpoint url (yes, ugh, but it happens when dealing with people used to some platforms) then that would be a genuinely useful thing to know. (FWIW, I've had problems with endpoint addresses too, due to strange interactions between CXF and Tomcat — arguably a Tomcat bug — but that's not relevant to your question.)